# How to count v-for object with if condition

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I try to count totalPaids(transaction.paid).

vue component:

```
          <tr v-if="studentFees" v-for="(studentFee, index) in studentFees">
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ index+1 }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ studentFee.programe }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ studentFee.level }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ studentFee.course_fee }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ studentFee.student_amount }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ studentFee.discount }}</td>

            <div v-for="studentTransaction in studentTransactions">
              <div v-if="studentTransaction.s_fee_id == studentFee.s_fee_id">
                  <td style="text-align: center;">{{ totalPaids(studentTransaction.paid) }}</td>
              </div>
            </div>
       </tr>
```

or see https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGoLo.png

in vue method:

```js
totalPaids(values){
    console.log(values)
}
```

**console.log**: `3000, 5000, 2000, 1000`

please help to sumation.

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I can not count that all values.

Comment: when i try to count in vue method. use values.forEach function that is an error this error are values,forEach in not a function.

Comment: is all your values in array? Or are you calling the function multiple times?

Comment: @monju Please let me know if the type of values is array or just variable.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGoLo.png please see that

Comment: values data must object.

Comment: `<div>` is an invalid direct child of `<tr>`. You want a functional component there, so that the resulting html is `tr > td`. Even if you have some invalid HTML which works as you expect it in some browsers for the time being, browsers don't care if and when that breaks. Their focus is on making all legal cases work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'p',
    sum:0
  },
  methods:{
        totalPaids: function(values){
         this.$data.sum+= Number(values);
         console.log( this.$data.sum);
         return  this.$data.sum;
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
     this.message=this.totalPaids(900);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

I would suggest you to register the variable in the data section to save it's state:

```
data: {
sum: 0,
},
```

Later modify the method `totalPaids` like this:

```
totalPaids(values){
 this.sum+= Number(values);
 console.log(sum);
 return sum;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Bahukhandi  work but many data ceeate. see console.log https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lPjQ.png

Comment: @monju did you define inside the data section?

Comment: @monju did you try to define `sum` inside `data` section? And I guess the method is being invoked infinite times.

Comment: I cannot see the image properly

Comment: But that is occurring due to the invocation and not definition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your values is an array of numbers then you can use the `reduce` method in JavaScript. So you can adjust your TotalPaid function to this:

```
totalPaids(values){
 var sum = values.reduce((sum, currentVal) => sum + currentVal);
 console.log(sum);
 return sum;
}
```

So this just takes your array of values, then runs through them adding the current value to the sum value each time.

Comment: Can you screenshot what console.log(values) displays? I don't know what values is... an object I'm guessing?